# How to pass through multiple requests on a route EXPRESS JS

Tags: express

I'm trying to pass through a view as well as a json file so that I can manipulate it within the view.`

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var data = require('../monsters.json');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
  res.json(data);
});

module.exports = router;
```

`

It passes through the render of the index.ejs view but in the console there is no indication of a json file with it. Nor is there any way to manipulate the file and read it. I'm not sure if I'm just being silly and the method for passing it through doesn't exist.

EDIT: I've now tried this and am pretty sure its being passed through, is there anyway I can verify that the file has been passed through? `

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
  res.header("Content-Type",'application/json');
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'monsters.json'));
});
```

`

Comment: You can't send multiple responses.  You get one response per request.  If the file you want to include is JSON, then perhaps you should embed it into a `<script>` tag in your HTML page using your template engine so everything would be in your HTML page and it can be the one response.  Then, the JSON will get parsed automatically into a Javascript object that is available to your page's Javascript.

Comment: Ah that makes a lot of sense. I'll give that a go and see how I get on. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send multiple responses. You get one response per request.

If the file you want to include is JSON, then you can embed it into a `<script>` tag in your HTML page using your template engine so everything would be in your HTML page and it can be the one response. Then, the JSON will get parsed automatically into a Javascript object that is available to your page's Javascript.

The other alternative is that you have the Javascript in the page make it's own Ajax call to your server to fetch the desired JSON in a separate http request.  You would then make a route on your web server for handling that Ajax request and sending back the desired file.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, you can't respond twice - you can however seemingly provide a callback to `res.render(view, locals, callback)` so perhaps you can serve it then. Otherwise, I would bake it into the view by generating the view on the backend with the file content as a parameter.

For more info, see;
http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render